# Affectiva Emotion SDK - Academic licensing

Tags: affdex-sdk, emotion

I would like to use this API for my Bachelor's Thesis in the area of context sensitive websites. My interpretation of the licensing agreement is that I am not allowed to use the API for any software development in academic research.  Since this is an individual project am I allowed to use the API under the free licensing agreement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDKs are [free](http://developer.affectiva.com/#pricing) for use in personal and open source projects and for companies generating less than $1,000,000 in yearly revenue. The only exclusion that we have is for academic and market research projects. Since this is an individual academic thesis you fall under the free tier. Feel free to use the SDK and let us know about your feedback and findings.